# How to find an element in mdspan

Tags: c++, std, c++23, mdspan

How to find an element in c++23 std::mdspan? Let's say there is some 2D mdspan. How can I find an element and get it's 2D indices?

I guess I can call data_handle() to get an access to underlaying data and do a 1D array search, but this will give me a 1D index. Does mdspan provide a method to map it back to 2D index?

Comment: I don't know the answer (not enough experience with mdspan yet), from what I gathered so far you can only reduce dimensionality not go back up. But I know this is a good presentation [Multidimensional C++ - Bryce Adelstein Lelbach - CppNorth 2022](https://youtu.be/aFCLmQEkPUw?si=kpJzIwdsmz252KDr) that covers the use of mdspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::ranges::find` with a custom projection.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main(){
    std::vector vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 88, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    auto ms = std::mdspan(vec.data(), 2, 6);

    auto coeff_view = std::views::cartesian_product(std::views::iota(0uz, ms.extent(0)),
                                        std::views::iota(0uz, ms.extent(1)));
    auto iter = std::ranges::find(coeff_view, 88, [ms](const auto rc){
        auto [r,c] = rc;
        return ms[r, c];
    });

    auto [foundr, foundc] = *iter;

    std::cout << foundr << "," << foundc << '\n';
}
```

The above outputs `1,1`.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/obW9jE3eW